# 1999 Mercury Sable flattened radiator hose

Tags: overheating, mercury, sable

My 1999 Mercury Sable is over heating and the radiator hose is going flat

Comment: Your first step is to replace the radiator hose.  It should not be flattening but when they get old they lose their rigidity and tend to flatten out and block the coolant flow.

Comment: If the radiator hose is going flat then it lacks coolant. So it will need refilling and bleeding.

Comment: Low coolant and/or a major blockage in coolant flow. The water pump is pulling a high vacuum making hose go flat.  I’m assuming this is the lower hose going flat?